# How to track down a Drupal max_allowed_packet error?

Tags: mysql, debugging, drupal, caching, drupal-6

One of my staging sites has recently started spewing **huge** errors on every admin page along the lines of:

`User warning: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes query: UPDATE cache_update SET data = '` ... `', created = 1298434692, expire = 1298438292, serialized = 1 WHERE cid = 'update_project_data' in _db_query() (line 141 of /var/www/vhosts/mysite/mypath/includes/database.mysqli.inc).` **(where "..." is about 1.5 million characters worth of serialized data)**

How should I go about tracking down where the error originates? Would adding debugging code to _db_query do any good, since it gets called so much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to track this down because you can't fix it I think.

This is the cache from update.module, containing information about which modules have updated versions and so on. So this is coming from one of the "_update_cache_set()" calls in that module.

Based on a wild guess, I'd say it is the one in this function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--update--update.fetch.inc/function/_update_refresh/6

It is basically building up an huge array with information about all projects on your site and tries to store it as a single, serialized value.

How many modules do you have installed on this site?

I can think of three ways to "fix" this error:

- Increase the max_allowed_packet size. (max_allowed_packet setting in my.conf)
- Disable update.module (It's not that useful on a staging/production site anyway, when you need to update on a dev site first anyway)
- Disable some modules ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check, there are probably some modules I can disable. Do you think disabling will be enough or will I need to uninstall them? Any idea why it refreshes that cache so often?

Comment: If you get that error, then the database is not updated. Next time it runs, the cache is still outdated and it tries to update it again. Disabling the modules should be enough to not look for updates for them, no idea if disabling a few modules will get rid of that error, though.

Comment: this helped me, thanks! update module in core - optional was a problem, it could not store huge blob and then added insult to injury and tried to log this massive blob in watchdog :/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and went round and round for about an hour.

Increased memory limit to `512m` and still had the issue. And figured that was enough. So went looking elsewhere.

I cleared the caches with drush, still the error, and then looked at the database tables.

I noticed that all the cache tables were cleared except cache_update. I truncated this table and bam, everything was working normally.

Before I got the memory limit error, I got a `max_input_vars` error since I am on `PHP5.4`. But this question and answer led me to this fix. Not quite sure how or why it worked, but it did.